# ImportError: libsasl2.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, hive, centos, anaconda, cloudera

I wrote this code :

```
from pyhive import hive

connection = hive.connect("quickstart.cloudera", username="cloudera",
                          port=10000)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM capacite_part"
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row[0], row[1])
```

and i get this :

```
In [6]: runfile('/home/cloudera/lire data capacite_part.py', wdir='/home/cloudera')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-c3cdfa2f79a9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/cloudera/lire data capacite_part.py', wdir='/home/cloudera')

  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/home/cloudera/lire data capacite_part.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pyhive import hive

  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 22, in <module>
    import sasl

  File "/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sasl/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from sasl.saslwrapper import *

ImportError: libsasl2.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

this is my config :

```
CLOUDERA CD5 CENTOS 6.7

Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
```

this is pip pkg :

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ pip freeze

```
alabaster==0.7.10
anaconda-client==1.6.3
anaconda-navigator==1.6.2
anaconda-project==0.6.0
asn1crypto==0.22.0
astroid==1.4.9
astropy==1.3.2
Babel==2.4.0
backports-abc==0.5
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
bitarray==0.8.1
blaze==0.10.1
bleach==1.5.0
bokeh==0.12.5
boto==2.46.1
Bottleneck==1.2.1
cdecimal==2.3
cffi==1.10.0
chardet==3.0.3
click==6.7
cloudpickle==0.2.2
clyent==1.2.2
colorama==0.3.9
conda==4.3.21
configparser==3.5.0
contextlib2==0.5.5
cryptography==1.8.1
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.25.2
cytoolz==0.8.2
dask==0.14.3
datashape==0.5.4
decorator==4.0.11
distributed==1.16.3
docutils==0.13.1
entrypoints==0.2.2
enum34==1.1.6
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.0.2
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.2
funcsigs==1.0.2
functools32==3.2.3.post2
future==0.16.0
futures==3.1.1
gevent==1.2.1
greenlet==0.4.12
grin==1.2.1
h5py==2.7.0
HeapDict==1.0.0
html5lib==0.999
idna==2.5
imagesize==0.7.1
ipaddress==1.0.18
ipykernel==4.6.1
ipython==5.3.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==6.0.0
isort==4.2.5
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.3
jedi==0.10.2
Jinja2==2.9.6
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.0.1
jupyter-console==5.1.0
jupyter-core==4.3.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.2.2
llvmlite==0.18.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml==3.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==2.0.2
mistune==0.7.4
mpmath==0.19
msgpack-python==0.4.8
multipledispatch==0.4.9
navigator-updater==0.1.0
nbconvert==5.1.1
nbformat==4.3.0
networkx==1.11
nltk==3.2.3
nose==1.3.7
notebook==5.0.0
numba==0.33.0+0.ge79330a.dirty
numexpr==2.6.2
numpy==1.12.1
numpydoc==0.6.0
odo==0.5.0
olefile==0.44
openpyxl==2.4.7
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.20.1
pandocfilters==1.4.1
partd==0.3.8
pathlib2==2.2.1
patsy==0.4.1
pep8==1.7.0
pexpect==4.2.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==4.1.1
ply==3.10
prompt-toolkit==1.0.14
psutil==5.2.2
ptyprocess==0.5.1
py==1.4.33
pycairo==1.10.0
pycosat==0.6.2
pycparser==2.17
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0
pyflakes==1.5.0
Pygments==2.2.0
PyHive==0.3.0
pylint==1.6.4
pyodbc==4.0.16
pyOpenSSL==17.0.0
pyparsing==2.1.4
pytest==3.0.7
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
PyWavelets==0.5.2
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==16.0.2
QtAwesome==0.4.4
qtconsole==4.3.0
QtPy==1.2.1
requests==2.14.2
rope==0.9.4
sasl==0.2.1
scandir==1.5
scikit-image==0.13.0
scikit-learn==0.18.1
scipy==0.19.0
seaborn==0.7.1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
sortedcollections==0.5.3
sortedcontainers==1.5.7
Sphinx==1.5.6
spyder==3.1.4
SQLAlchemy==1.1.9
statsmodels==0.8.0
subprocess32==3.2.7
sympy==1.0
tables==3.3.0
tblib==1.3.2
terminado==0.6
testpath==0.3
thrift==0.10.0
thrift-sasl==0.2.1
toolz==0.8.2
tornado==4.5.1
traitlets==4.3.2
unicodecsv==0.14.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
Werkzeug==0.12.2
widgetsnbextension==2.0.0
wrapt==1.10.10
xlrd==1.0.0
XlsxWriter==0.9.6
xlwt==1.2.0
zict==0.1.2
```

Anybody has an idea of why it 's not working ?

thanks a lot in advance ...

(i have already, before, installed a newest Anaconda distribution, with Python 3.6 ...it was making the same thing...)

Where can i get a new libsasl2.so.3 for a centos 6.7 and for x64 bits...?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing a very similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes these version problems can be resolved by creating a symbolic link with another version of the same library. If you have **libsasl2.so** installed, create a linked file **libsasl2.so.2** for the same:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2
```

Comment: Is this even safe to do if they're different and not just named differently?

Comment: Not an expert in this area but while troubleshooting, I have observed that in most of the cases, these are different versions of the same library and unless there has been a drastic change, they work just fine. One very common example is that you have a requirement of v58 of a particular library for your distribution e.g. CentOS 7 while v58 has not been released for CentOS7 yet. The maximum version available for CentOS 7 is v55, so you need to create a symlink from v55 to v58.

Comment: For more in depth understanding, please refer to the following thread [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work) or relevant kernel/gcc documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Activate the environment you want and enter the following in UNIX to check where the environment is stored

```
which python
```

Let's say it returned the following:

```
/u/jane/.conda/envs/python378/bin/python
```

Now use the above directory and replace it with lib path.
You need to create a soft link using the existing **libsasl2.so** library, which can be done using the following command

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so /u/jane/.conda/envs/python378/lib/libsasl2.so.2
```